# how to solve the exception in android

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, httprequest

i have written HttpDelete in android to call REST web service.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txt.setText(getInputStreamFromUrl("http://192.168.37.241:8080/kyaw/k"));
    }

    public static String getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {
          InputStream content = null;
          HttpResponse response = null;
          try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();             
            HttpDelete delete=new HttpDelete(url);
            put.setHeader("Content-Type","application/vnd.org.snia.cdmi.container");
            response = httpclient.execute(delete);
            content = response.getEntity().getContent();
          }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("[DELETE REQUEST]", "Network exception");
          }
            String result=response.getStatusLine().toString()+"\n"+response.getHeaders(url);
            return result;
        }
```

And I get the exception which is

```
05-23 08:30:16.868: ERROR/[DELETE REQUEST](1197): Network exception
05-23 08:30:16.868: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1197): Shutting down VM
05-23 08:30:16.878: WARN/dalvikvm(1197): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-23 08:30:16.908: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1197): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 08:30:16.908: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1197): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.putandroid}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Do anyone know why?

Comment: hi andreas_D, i got NullPointerException  .This is log file 05-23 08:41:27.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1344): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 08:41:27.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1344): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.putandroid}: java.lang.NullPointerException
: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check for the manifest file for Internet permission?

Comment: hi user755060,  I forget to add permission . Now solve it.thanks

Answer (score 0):

No idea for the network exception (yet) but the last NPE is most likely because the previous exception is thrown before `response` has been initialized through `httpclient.execute(delete)`.

You should rewrite your `catch` block and write the name of the catched exception and the message to the log.

Comment: 05-23 08:41:27.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1344):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-23 08:41:27.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1344):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-23 08:41:27.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1344):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-23 08:41:27.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1344):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-23 08:41:27.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1344): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate() function on line 4 we find that after initializing your `TextView` you are trying to set a value.

You must use a `Handler` object because you cannot update an UI objects while in a separate thread.

Here is some link for your help

https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html

https://web.archive.org/web/20130306131310/http://thedevelopersinfo.com/?p=150